# Show ajax tooltip from an SVG onclick event

Tags: javascript, ajax, svg

I have an SVG with this code for some shapes (its a map)

```
onclick="top.traeDatos(evt.target.id);"
```

in the html file I have:

```
function traeDatos(region){
    alert(region);
}
```

So, I click on a region, I have the alert window with the region name and the variable in the html file. Thats great

Now I want that the click on the map shows a popup with more information i'll get using ajax from multiple databases trough a file called, for example "getDetails.php".

Im new in js and ajax, I know how to make a standard call in ajax to get some information given an id (or name in this case), I know how to change the value of a text field to the text I get trought the ajax call...but I dont understand how to call ajax and show a tooltip from that javascript code in the SVG or the one in html.

Im not sure too of what tolltip to use, but one problem at the time ;)

Can you enlighten me a little.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
function traeDatos(region){
    var domn = document.domain;
    document.domain = domn;
    var detURL = "http://" + domn + "/getDetails.php";
    $.ajax({
        url: detURL,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            region: region
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(json){
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
            //using PHP's json_encode() you can return an array
            //in the example below 'info' is an item in the array
            $('#insert_place').val(data.info);
        }
    });
}
```

Let me know if you have some problem with that.